# Redmine + Lighttpd: fails to load javascripts (404)

Tags: javascript, http-status-code-404, lighttpd, redmine

I've a strange problem with my redmine/lighttpd installation under ubuntu 11.10. I've installed and configured redmine and it's working like it should be but: everything works fine except that all javascript files under /javascripts are not found!? But everything under "/stylesheets" or "/themes" is loaded properly.

The strange thing is that when I call "myserver.com/javascripts/" it returns 404. If I copy the javascripts directory to "js" and call "myserver.com/js/" I get the directory listing from lighttpd!

This is my lighttpd.conf for my redmine installation:

```
$HTTP["host"] == "myserver.com" {
    server.document-root = "/var/www/redmine/public/"
    server.indexfiles = ( "dispatch.fcgi" )
    server.error-handler-404 = "/dispatch.fcgi"
    server.errorlog = "/var/log/lighttpd/redmine/error.log"
    accesslog.filename = "/var/log/lighttpd/redmine/access.log"
    fastcgi.server    = ( ".fcgi" =>
        ((
            "bin-path" => "/var/www/redmine/public/dispatch.fcgi",
            "socket" => "/tmp/ruby-rails.socket",
            "max-procs" => 5,
            "idle-timeout" => 20,
            "bin-environment" => (
                "RAILS_ENV" => "production",
                "RAILS_ROOT" => "/var/www/redmine"
            ),
        ))
    )
}
```

Any ideas???

Edit:

I've put an debug.log-request-handling = "enable" in my lighttpd.conf.

I get this for calling "/stylesheets":

```
2011-12-01 11:25:58: (response.c.300) -- splitting Request-URI 
2011-12-01 11:25:58: (response.c.301) Request-URI  :  /stylesheets/ 
2011-12-01 11:25:58: (response.c.302) URI-scheme   :  http 
2011-12-01 11:25:58: (response.c.303) URI-authority:  redmine.musik-sammler.de 
2011-12-01 11:25:58: (response.c.304) URI-path     :  /stylesheets/ 
2011-12-01 11:25:58: (response.c.305) URI-query    :   
2011-12-01 11:25:58: (response.c.349) -- sanatising URI 
2011-12-01 11:25:58: (response.c.350) URI-path     :  /stylesheets/ 
2011-12-01 11:25:58: (response.c.470) -- before doc_root 
2011-12-01 11:25:58: (response.c.471) Doc-Root     : /var/www/redmine/public/ 
2011-12-01 11:25:58: (response.c.472) Rel-Path     : /stylesheets/ 
2011-12-01 11:25:58: (response.c.473) Path         :  
2011-12-01 11:25:58: (response.c.521) -- after doc_root 
2011-12-01 11:25:58: (response.c.522) Doc-Root     : /var/www/redmine/public/ 
2011-12-01 11:25:58: (response.c.523) Rel-Path     : /stylesheets/ 
2011-12-01 11:25:58: (response.c.524) Path         : /var/www/redmine/public/stylesheets/ 
2011-12-01 11:25:58: (response.c.541) -- logical -> physical 
2011-12-01 11:25:58: (response.c.542) Doc-Root     : /var/www/redmine/public/ 
2011-12-01 11:25:58: (response.c.543) Rel-Path     : /stylesheets/ 
2011-12-01 11:25:58: (response.c.544) Path         : /var/www/redmine/public/stylesheets/ 
2011-12-01 11:25:58: (response.c.561) -- handling physical path 
2011-12-01 11:25:58: (response.c.562) Path         : /var/www/redmine/public/stylesheets/ 
2011-12-01 11:25:58: (response.c.569) -- file found 
2011-12-01 11:25:58: (response.c.570) Path         : /var/www/redmine/public/stylesheets/ 
2011-12-01 11:25:58: (response.c.719) -- handling subrequest 
2011-12-01 11:25:58: (response.c.720) Path         : /var/www/redmine/public/stylesheets/ 
2011-12-01 11:25:58: (mod_indexfile.c.150) -- handling the request as Indexfile 
2011-12-01 11:25:58: (mod_indexfile.c.151) URI          : /stylesheets/ 
2011-12-01 11:25:58: (mod_compress.c.683) -- handling file as static file 
2011-12-01 11:25:58: (mod_dirlisting.c.922) -- handling the request as Dir-Listing 
2011-12-01 11:25:58: (mod_dirlisting.c.923) URI          : /stylesheets/ 
2011-12-01 11:25:58: (response.c.731) -- subrequest finished
```

And this for calling "/javascripts":

```
2011-12-01 11:24:38: (response.c.300) -- splitting Request-URI 
2011-12-01 11:24:38: (response.c.301) Request-URI  :  /javascripts/ 
2011-12-01 11:24:38: (response.c.302) URI-scheme   :  http 
2011-12-01 11:24:38: (response.c.303) URI-authority:  redmine.musik-sammler.de 
2011-12-01 11:24:38: (response.c.304) URI-path     :  /javascripts/ 
2011-12-01 11:24:38: (response.c.305) URI-query    :   
2011-12-01 11:24:38: (response.c.349) -- sanatising URI 
2011-12-01 11:24:38: (response.c.350) URI-path     :  /javascripts/ 
2011-12-01 11:24:38: (response.c.470) -- before doc_root 
2011-12-01 11:24:38: (response.c.471) Doc-Root     : /var/www/redmine/public/ 
2011-12-01 11:24:38: (response.c.472) Rel-Path     : /javascripts/ 
2011-12-01 11:24:38: (response.c.473) Path         :  
2011-12-01 11:24:38: (response.c.521) -- after doc_root 
2011-12-01 11:24:38: (response.c.522) Doc-Root     : /var/www/redmine/public/ 
2011-12-01 11:24:38: (response.c.523) Rel-Path     : /javascripts/ 
2011-12-01 11:24:38: (response.c.524) Path         : /var/www/redmine/public/javascripts/ 
2011-12-01 11:24:38: (response.c.541) -- logical -> physical 
2011-12-01 11:24:38: (response.c.542) Doc-Root     : /var/www/redmine/public/ 
2011-12-01 11:24:38: (response.c.543) Rel-Path     : /javascripts/ 
2011-12-01 11:24:38: (response.c.544) Path         : /usr/share/javascripts/ 
2011-12-01 11:24:38: (response.c.561) -- handling physical path 
2011-12-01 11:24:38: (response.c.562) Path         : /usr/share/javascripts/ 
2011-12-01 11:24:38: (response.c.618) -- file not found 
2011-12-01 11:24:38: (response.c.619) Path         : /usr/share/javascripts/ 
2011-12-01 11:24:38: (response.c.300) -- splitting Request-URI 
2011-12-01 11:24:38: (response.c.301) Request-URI  :  /dispatch.fcgi 
2011-12-01 11:24:38: (response.c.302) URI-scheme   :  http 
2011-12-01 11:24:38: (response.c.303) URI-authority:  redmine.musik-sammler.de 
2011-12-01 11:24:38: (response.c.304) URI-path     :  /dispatch.fcgi 
2011-12-01 11:24:38: (response.c.305) URI-query    :   
2011-12-01 11:24:38: (response.c.349) -- sanatising URI 
2011-12-01 11:24:38: (response.c.350) URI-path     :  /dispatch.fcgi 
2011-12-01 11:24:38: (response.c.470) -- before doc_root 
2011-12-01 11:24:38: (response.c.471) Doc-Root     : /var/www/redmine/public/ 
2011-12-01 11:24:38: (response.c.472) Rel-Path     : /dispatch.fcgi 
2011-12-01 11:24:38: (response.c.473) Path         :  
2011-12-01 11:24:38: (response.c.521) -- after doc_root 
2011-12-01 11:24:38: (response.c.522) Doc-Root     : /var/www/redmine/public/ 
2011-12-01 11:24:38: (response.c.523) Rel-Path     : /dispatch.fcgi 
2011-12-01 11:24:38: (response.c.524) Path         : /var/www/redmine/public/dispatch.fcgi 
2011-12-01 11:24:38: (response.c.541) -- logical -> physical 
2011-12-01 11:24:38: (response.c.542) Doc-Root     : /var/www/redmine/public/ 
2011-12-01 11:24:38: (response.c.543) Rel-Path     : /dispatch.fcgi 
2011-12-01 11:24:38: (response.c.544) Path         : /var/www/redmine/public/dispatch.fcgi 
2011-12-01 11:24:38: (response.c.561) -- handling physical path 
2011-12-01 11:24:38: (response.c.562) Path         : /var/www/redmine/public/dispatch.fcgi 
2011-12-01 11:24:38: (response.c.569) -- file found 
2011-12-01 11:24:38: (response.c.570) Path         : /var/www/redmine/public/dispatch.fcgi 
2011-12-01 11:24:38: (response.c.719) -- handling subrequest 
2011-12-01 11:24:38: (response.c.720) Path         : /var/www/redmine/public/dispatch.fcgi 
2011-12-01 11:24:38: (mod_compress.c.683) -- handling file as static file 
2011-12-01 11:24:38: (mod_fastcgi.c.3703) handling it in mod_fastcgi
```

Why is there this jump from /var/www/redmine to /usr/share?????

Answer (score 3):

Had the same issue and finally solved it: You probably have the javascript-alias mod enabled which contains

```
alias.url += ("/javascript" => "/usr/share/javascript")
```

Just do

```
sudo lighty-disable-mod javascript-alias
```

I tracked it down to the [javascript-common](http://packages.ubuntu.com/oneiric/javascript-common) package.

Thanks for posting the debug info, it helped me a lot to identify mod_alias as the cause of the problem.

Comment: Thanks, that's a sneaky one! also had this issue on one of my older apps.

Answer (score 0):

From the information you present the javascript folder is a symlink referencing /usr/share/javascripts.

Comment: Not, it's not a symlink. I would've seen that.